# Use PowerShell to iterate through all WebConfiguration Properties for IIS

Tags: asp.net, windows, powershell, iis

I want to try to iterate through all the available configuration options that an Application has in IIS so I can set them via PowerShell. I'm not all the familiar with IIS or PowerShell so I'm doing my best. The following output is what I get when I attempt to iterate through all the configurations for an Application.

```
PS C:\Users\User01> $siteName = "CustomApp"
PS C:\Users\User01> $authentications = Get-WebConfiguration -filter "system.webServer/*" -PSPath "IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\$siteName"
PS C:\Users\User01> foreach ($auth in $authentications) { Write-Host $auth }
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationSection
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationSection
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationSection
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationSection
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationSection
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationSection
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationSection
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationSection
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationSection
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationSection
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationSection
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationSection
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationSection
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationSection
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationSection
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationSection
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationSection
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationSection
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationSection
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationSection
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationSection
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationSection
PS C:\Users\User01> $authentications = Get-WebConfiguration -filter "system.webServer/*" -PSPath "IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\$siteName" -Recurse
PS C:\Users\User01> foreach ($auth in $authentications) { Write-Host $auth }
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationSection
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationSection
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationSection
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationSection
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationSection
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationSection
```

What should I do to get the actual item name instead of what's being shown?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the -recurse function to iterate through all of them.

Comment: I added the `-recurse` flag and same result.

Answer (score -2):

Try this instead of your 'Write-Host'

```
{$auth|gm}
```